# Eclipse: Unable to find a GPG key for signing (verify through Eclipse)

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

I've tried everything I could find on the internet and nothing helped.
When trying to commit signed from Eclipse IDE, I'm getting an error starting with *Unable to find a GPG key for signing*

What I've done:
Read all related StackOverflow questions.
Read https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/generating-a-new-gpg-key, installed "Simple installer for the current GnuPG".
Read https://gist.github.com/BoGnY/f9b1be6393234537c3e247f33e74094a, and all it's comments, understood, that Git comes with GPG inside of it, deleted installed GnuPG instance from program files x86.

My IDE statistics:

```
Eclipse Platform

Version: 4.19.0.v20210303-1800
Build id: I20210303-1800

Eclipse EGit
Git integration for Eclipse - UI
5.10.0.202012080955-r
```

To verify that Eclipse configuration window doesn't lie about my system state, I've checked everything from Git Bash:

```
$ git version
git version 2.33.1.windows.1
```

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.29-unknown
libgcrypt 1.9.3-unknown
```

```
$ where gpg
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe
```

```
$ git config --global --list
user.name=[My proper name, identical to author/commiter, identical to GitHub real name]
user.email=[My proper email, identical to verified on GitHub, identical to the one in GitHub assigned GPG key]
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
commit.gpgsign=true
gpg.program=C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gpg.exe
```

```
$ gpg -K
/c/Users/[my username]/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
[and next goes info about my key. It is assosiated with my ID, marked as [ultimate]]
```

So, after 4 hours and countless articles I can't get this to work. I'm suspecting that Eclipse does not understand where to look for my pubring.kbx, through it seems that /c/Users/[your username]/.gnupg/ is the default installation folder for GPG.
Acording to comments in the post: [Use gpg to sign git commits in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603475/use-gpg-to-sign-git-commits-in-eclipse) it is unclear, but stated:

> Keys will be looked up from your GPG keyring (either
> ~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx or ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg; on Windows the directory
> %APPDATA%\gnupg is used—if it exists—instead of ~/.gnupg).

Where is my magic pill?

P.S. Adding

```
user.signingkey=[my secret key representation]
```

Does not help either. And it whould work without it, because I should find a key, associated with user email, right?..

Comment: Also, I don't know if this is important or not, but when I was creating my key, I could not make a passphrase and left it blank. Because literally anything I would type to the popup window says "bad passphrase".

Comment: Why are you using an outdated Eclipse with outdated EGit? Did you read the EGit documentation?

Comment: @howlger yes, I've read about EGit 5.11, and it's major changes to signing. I can't update IDE now, because it is actually not blank Eclipse, but rather an IDE based off Eclipse, so I've contacted a vendor of my IDE to update their core.
BUT it is still ridiculous that after so many versions of EGit (my version is end of 2020) this was still broken for so long and I can barely find any information on the internet about people complaining about this.
I'll close for now, untill my IDE vendor updates. Sorry for distraction.

Comment: You are making wrong conclusions based on wrong assumptions (to learn the basics you have to read the documentation, not Stack Overflow answers). The command line Git (git-core) and JGit (on which EGit is based) are different implementations each with its own documentation. Another of your wrong assumptions seems to be that you don't know that you can update plugins like EGit without updating the whole IDE. There is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key#telling-git-about-your-gpg-key-1 step 3 is what you're looking for.

***tl;dr:***

- Call `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long`:

```
$ gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long
/Users/hubot/.gnupg/secring.gpg
------------------------------------
sec   4096R/3AA5C34371567BD2 2016-03-10 [expires: 2017-03-10]
uid                          Hubot 
ssb   4096R/42B317FD4BA89E7A 2016-03-10
```

- `3AA5C34371567BD2` is your sign key
- Add it to your gitconfig: `git config --global user.signingkey 3AA5C34371567BD2`

To make this work with Eclipse (EGit) you have to reference your gpg installation in Eclipse as described here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/5.11#Using_GPG_to_Sign_Commits_and_Tags